# Laravel 5.6: Error creating new database with command

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I want to create a database using a command. I am using postgresql. I am creating the tables using the migrations but before that I want to create the database and several schemas.
I am using this command:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class pgsql extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'pgsql:createdb {name?}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create a new pgsql database schema based on the database config file';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $dbname = env('DB_DATABASE');
        $dbuser = env('DB_USERNAME');
        $dbpass = env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $dbhost = env('DB_HOST');

        try {
            $db = new \PDO("pgsql:host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass);
            $test = $db->exec("CREATE DATABASE \"$dbname\" WITH TEMPLATE = template0 encoding = 'UTF8' lc_collate='Spanish_Spain.1252' lc_ctype='Spanish_Spain.1252';");
            if($test === false) 
                throw new \Exception($db->errorInfo()[2]);
            $this->info(sprintf('Successfully created %s database', $dbname));
        }
        catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->error(sprintf('Failed to create %s database: %s', $dbname, $exception->getMessage()));
        }

    }
}
```

But I get this error:

`Failed to create  database: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "connect_timeout=30" to address: Unknown server error`

Like I said I want to create a new database in Laravel, I am using this way but is not working, if there is other way to do it I would like to know.

**EDIT1:** It works fine now, I just pick the values from the config like you said @Dimitri Mostrey :

```
$dbname = config('database.connections.pgsql.database');
$dbuser = config('database.connections.pgsql.username');
$dbpass = config('database.connections.pgsql.password');
$dbhost = config('database.connections.pgsql.host');
```

Comment: did you try PDO("pgsql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$db;user=$dbuser;password=$dbpass");  ?

Comment: I used like this:
`$db = new \PDO("pgsql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;user=$dbuser;password=$dbpass");`

But I get this error:
`Failed to create  database: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "dbname=" to address: Unknown server error`

Comment: which is the host name?

Comment: Is this on a working server or a test server? On a working server the helper `env()` doesn't work, for security reasons. You have to pick the values from  the config. `config('database.connections.pgsql.database')` etc.

Comment: Is my localhost, 127.0.0.1